# Microsoft Teams Chatbot Not Responding - Integration With IBM Watson Bot

Tags: ibm-watson, microsoft-teams

I have done the integration of IBM Watson Bot with the Microsoft Teams but the chatbot is not responding. Whereas, same integration with Skype working pretty well. I tried debugging the chatbot using the bot emulator and it's working there. Kindly help on this. Thanks in advance.

Below is the log for Bot Emulator:

```
[13:26:34] -> POST 202 [message] hello 
    [13:26:35] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Hello 
    [13:26:35] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event 
    [13:26:38] -> POST 202 [message] hi 
    [13:26:39] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Hola 
    [13:26:39] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event 
    [13:26:46] -> POST 202 [message] status of Ankita 
    [13:26:48] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Status of Ankita is RolledOn! 
    [13:26:48] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event 
    [13:56:20] -> POST 202 [conversationUpdate] 
    [13:56:20] -> POST 202 [conversationUpdate] 
    [13:56:31] -> POST 202 [message] Hi 
    [13:56:32] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event 
    [13:56:33] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Hola 
    [13:56:33] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event
```

Comment: Could you please share the bot Id? Have you added Microsoft Teams as a channel in your bot? Please have a look at [create a bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create#create-a-bot-for-microsoft-teams) documentation.

Comment: Hi Wajeed, I have added the Microsoft teams as a channel and skype as well.I am able to get the response from the Skype but not with Teams.Day before yesterday I was getting the response in Teams as well but suddenly its not working.Could you please look into this?

Comment: Could you please share the bot id? Also, if you can test it once by registring a new bot.

Comment: This is the bot id "49a29f1f-3dc5-45ba-b6dc-ccc8d22a704e".I have registered a new bot but that is also not working.Test in web chat is working for the new bot and skype but not with Teams.

Comment: I tried your bot ( 49a29f1f-3dc5-45ba-b6dc-ccc8d22a704e -  PMO_Digital), it's responding to me. 
Bot's reply - "What is the status of Anjani When is Sundar birthday? What is the roll on date of Ravi When is Ankita ACN anniversary?"
Could you please try your bot with some other user and confirm?